# How to add object in selected index in listview

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I add element(object) to the first index int listview? In the example at the picture  at the first index 'esspreso' I want to add some ingredient,how to make it? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW1rF.png)

this is the code which I use for displaying the drinks

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0,-20} {1,25}", this.GetType().Name, this.Price));
    foreach (Ingredient ingredient in ingredients)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(ingredient.ToString());
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

this is the code which displays the ingredients

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("- {0,-20} {1,30}", this.GetType().Name, this.Price);
}
private void ShowInformation(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendLine("Bill:");
    foreach (Coffee coffee in coffes)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(coffee.ToString());
    }
    builder.AppendLine();
    Result.Text = builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You can use one of [`ListView.Items.Insert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydfzwwb7(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads.

Comment: To take screenshot of active window, you can press Alt + PrtSc and then paste it in Paint. This way the screenshot contains only the active window not the whole desktop.

Comment: thanks Reza.But it dont works the way i want...:(

Comment: Your question has some irrelevant code. Make a clean code which you try to insert an item in specific index and then if you had problem, share the clean code with description about the specific problem which you have. Currently you asked *How to add object in selected index in ListView* and the answer of this question is exactly the first comment :)